Resolving secret during Cloud Build not working?
My Dockerfile requires the GITHUB_TOKEN to be set in order to be able to download and install an npm package.
Hence, my Dockerfile an argument GITHUB_TOKEN. This is working fine locally.
The problem occurs as I try to do this in the context of my Cloud Build run.
As stated by the docs:

When specifying the secret in the args field, specify it using the environment variable prefixed with $$.

Which is what I do, as you can see:
cloudbuild.yaml
substitutions:
  _IMAGE: ''
  _IMAGE_VERSION: ''

options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY

steps:

  # Build image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      [
        'build',
        '--build-arg', 'GITHUB_TOKEN=$$GITHUB_TOKEN',
        '-t', '$_IMAGE:$_IMAGE_VERSION',
        '.'
      ]
    secretEnv: ['GITHUB_TOKEN']

# Same result with:

#  # Build image
#  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
#    entrypoint: 'bash'
#    args:
#      [
#        '-c',
#        'docker build --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN=$$GITHUB_TOKEN -t $_IMAGE:$_IMAGE_VERSION .'
#      ]
#    secretEnv: ['GITHUB_TOKEN']

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/${PROJECT_ID}/secrets/GITHUB_TOKEN/versions/latest
      env: GITHUB_TOKEN

The result being a 401 Unauthorized error:

401 Unauthorized - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/****** - unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided.

Dockerfile
This, as mentioned, is working locally without issues:
FROM node:20-alpine3.20 AS homepage
RUN apk update && apk add bash

ARG GITHUB_TOKEN
ENV GITHUB_NPM_PAT=${GITHUB_TOKEN}

WORKDIR /homepage

COPY web/homepage/.npmrc ./
COPY web/homepage/*.json ./
RUN npm i

COPY web/homepage/ ./
RUN npm run build

build.yaml
This is how the build gets triggered in my GitHub Actions:
- name: Prepare substitutions
  # NOTE: Substitutions are comma separated: KEY1=VAL1,KEY2=VAL2
  run: |
    echo -n '_IMAGE=${{ env.IMAGE }},' > .substitutions
    echo -n '_IMAGE_VERSION=${{ env.IMAGE_VERSION }}' >> .substitutions
    cat .substitutions

- name: Cloud Build
  run: |      
    gcloud builds submit . --substitutions=$(cat .substitutions)


I wasn't able to read the signs but the problem started much earlier. The mistake I made was in the cloudbuild.yaml. In order to keep the GITHUB_TOKEN up-to-date, I check if it changed and run:
echo ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} | gcloud secrets versions add $SECRET_NAME --data-file=-

The problem here is that echo appends a \n. I should have used
echo -n ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} | gcloud secrets versions add $SECRET_NAME --data-file=-
     ^^

Instead.

⚠️ Please note, that npm i will actually print the Bearer token to standard output, potentially leaking your secret, in this case.

I found this in the Cloud Build log output:
Step #0: [0m[91mnpm error Bearer <my entire GitHub token>
Step #0: npm error is not a legal HTTP header value

With
  # Build image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        docker build \
          -t "$_IMAGE:$_IMAGE_VERSION" \
          --build-arg "GITHUB_TOKEN=$$GITHUB_TOKEN" .
    secretEnv: ['GITHUB_TOKEN']

and the corrected echo, the build finally works.
